# The parameterized query expects'@firstname nvarchar, @lastname nvarchar, @phone nvarchar expects the parameter @email, which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql

Are there any gurus out there that might be able to help me figure this out?  I keep throwing this exception in C#, but everything that I can see seems to be correct.  Here is the code

```
  public bool Insert(loginBLL u)
    {
        bool isSuccess = false;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstrng);

        try
        {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO customers (firstname, lastname, phone, email, address, city, state, zipcode, password, username) VALUES (@firstname, @lastname, @phone, @email, @address, @city, @state, @zipcode, @password, @username)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", u.firstname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", u.lastname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", u.phone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", u.email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", u.address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", u.city);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", u.state);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zipcode", u.zipcode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", u.password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", u.username);

         
            conn.Open();

            int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I would recommend avoiding `AddWithValue()` and instead adding the parameters with explicit types.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so instead use cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType,varchar);

Comment: And null values? `.AddWithValue("xxx", u.xxx ?? DBNull.Value);`

Comment: Check for all the parameters, you are passing null to a non-nullable column, I would suggest to use parameters.add

Comment: `u.email` is `null` (check the duplicate).

Comment: @viveknuna `you are passing null to a non-nullable column` Nullability of the column is not relevant. The OP is passing `null` when they should be passing `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: @JoeW. I'd consider using Dapper or PetaPoco or similar - using a lightweight ORM like that avoids you having to worry about issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is due to passing `(object)null` instead of `DBNull.Value` for null parameters.

These days, I'd avoid all that parameter boilerplate by writing an extension method to bind parameters from a `FormattableString`.

```cs
        public static SqlCommand GetCommandInterpolated(this SqlConnection conn, FormattableString sql)
        {
            var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            var replacements = new string[sql.ArgumentCount];
            var args = sql.GetArguments();

            for (int i = 0; i < sql.ArgumentCount; i++)
            {
                var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                p.ParameterName = replacements[i] = $"@p_{i}";
                p.Value = args[i] ?? DBNull.Value;
            }
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format(sql.Format, replacements);
            return cmd;
        }


        var cmd = conn.GetCommandInterpolated(
            $@"INSERT INTO customers (firstname, lastname, phone, email, address, city, state, zipcode, password, username)
            VALUES ({u.firstname}, {u.lastname}, {u.phone}, {u.email}, {u.address}, {u.city}, {u.state}, {u.zipcode}, {u.password}, {u.username}"
        );
```

Comment: Thank you all.  Problem solved only to create a new one.  Appreciate all of the input and help